# python: how to close orphaned domain socket from new process

Tags: python, sockets, unix-socket

I planing to use domain sockets as lock to ensure only one active instance (Linux kernel >=2.6).

So, I am binding a domain socket to the active process and create also a lock file with the PID for a more human-friendly check option in the fs.

```
import socket
class processLock(object):
    def __init__(self, processName):
        self.processName = processName
        self.PIDfile = os.path.join(self.getTMPDIR(),"UID-%s_PROCESS-%s.pid" % (os.getuid(), processName) )
        ...
        self.socket.bind('\0' + self.processName)
        ...
        atexit.register(self.cleanup)
    ...
    def cleanup(self):
        self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.socket.close()
        self.socketOK = False
        os.remove(self.PIDfile)
```

It is generally working, but now I managed to kill a process hard so that it did not close its socket at exit and the socket is kept open beyond the process' lifetime:

```
> lsof
   condorJob 124485        root    4u     unix 0xffff88186c3341c0        0t0  175181414 @TestFooName
   condorJob 124485        root    5w      REG                8,6          0   13893673 /var/tmp/UID-0_PROCESS-TestFooName.pid (deleted)
```

Since I have a PID file as cross-check, I would like to close the socket (after sanity checking in the process tree to be the only one). However, I cannot bind to the socket from a new instance since it is still bound as a ~*zombie socket*.

Is there a python way to close existing unix domain sockets (running as pid 0 if necessary)?

Answer (score 1):

It was a mistake on my side. I had sent manually the process to sleep in another tab and I did not realized it despite lsof showing the PID. After killing the process, the kernel closed the socket as intended. So everything is working as expected.